Custom x labels for facet_wrap plot
I want only X labels to be plotted for periods where I have data.
This is my code now:

  ggplot(expanded_data, aes(x = as.factor(date))) +
    geom_rect(data = expanded_data %>%
                filter(loc == "M2"),
              aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 535, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "gray90", alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_rect(data = expanded_data %>%
                filter(loc == "M2"),
              aes(xmin = 976, xmax = 1219, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "gray90", alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_rect(data = expanded_data %>%
                filter(loc == "M1"),
              aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 975, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "gray90", alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_rect(data = expanded_data %>%
                filter(loc == "Fram"),
              aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 243, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "gray90", alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_rect(data = expanded_data %>%
                filter(loc == "Fram"),
              aes(xmin = 488, xmax = 975, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "gray90", alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    ...
    
    
    geom_col(aes(y=total_presence, fill = "Presence"), width = 1, position = "stack") +
    geom_col(aes(y=total_song, fill = "Song"), width = 1, position = "stack") +
    facet_wrap(~ loc, scales = "free", ncol = 1, strip.position="right") +
    labs(x="Date", y="Total Detections")+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,24, by = 6), limits = c(0, 24), expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) ifelse(grepl("-01$", x), substr(month.abb[as.numeric(substr(x, 6, 7))], 1, 1), "")) +  
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Presence" = "#f5776d", "Song" = "#00bfc4"), name = "Detections") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(0.3, "lines"),
          panel.grid = element_line(color = "white", linetype = "solid", size = 0.1),
          strip.text = element_text(hjust = 0, vjust =1, angle = 0),
          axis.text.x = element_text((size = 6)),
          panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA))+
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Legend"))
  

and the plot looks like:
plot
while I want it to contain only x labels for periods where there is data like this:
desired plot

> print(expanded_data)
       loc       date total_presence total_song
1      12E 2017-10-01             NA         NA
2      25E 2017-10-01             NA         NA
3   Atwain 2017-10-01              0          0
4     Fram 2017-10-01             NA         NA
5       M1 2017-10-01             NA         NA
6       M2 2017-10-01             NA         NA
7      12E 2017-10-02             NA         NA
8      25E 2017-10-02             NA         NA
9   Atwain 2017-10-02              0          0
10    Fram 2017-10-02             NA         NA
11      M1 2017-10-02             NA         NA
12      M2 2017-10-02             NA         NA


I tried to add the condition to scale_x_discrete like this:
scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) ifelse(grepl("-01$", x) & !is.na(expanded_data$total_presence), substr(month.abb[as.numeric(substr(x, 6, 7))], 1, 1), "")) +  


But it didn't work

I am not sure this is possible with facet_*

As a hack, it might work to remove all x-axis labels and instead "plot" the ones you want with geom_text.

Better idea: I think ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales will let you do it. I don't have time now to write up an answer, maybe someone else will (even you!).

I am not managing to work with facetted_pos_scales.. Thanks for the tips tho! I will try to plot the labels with geom_text but is there a way then to set the coordinates exactly to the right locations using the daterange?
